# Is the product of two topological groups a topological group?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, product-space

Let $G_1,G_2$ be two [topological groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group), with group multiplication given by $\mu_1:G_1 \times G_1 \rightarrow G_1$ and $\mu_2:G_2 \times G_2 \rightarrow G_2$, and inverses $i_1, i_2$ resepctively.

Let $G_1 \times G_2$ be given the product topology, we define,

$$ \mu: (G_1 \times G_2) \times (G_1 \times G_2) \rightarrow (G_1 \times G_2)$$
by $\mu( (a,b) , (c,d)) = ( \mu_1(a,c), \mu_2(b,d))$ and inverse $i(a,b) = (i_1(a), i_2(b))$.

> **Q.** Is $G_1 \times G_2$ also a topological group?

---

It can be shown that $i^{-1}(U \times V) = i_1^{-1}(U) \times i_2^{-1}(V)$ is open. So the inverse map is continuous. But
$$ \mu^{-1}( U \times V) = ?$$

Comment: The given answer is correct and precise, but the high level understanding here is that just as $i = (i_1, i_2)$, also $\mu = (\mu_1, \mu_2)$ (at least, up to some rearranging of factors). Everything about the groups happens independently on both components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's a topological group. To show $\mu:(G_1\times G_2)
\times(G_1\times G_2)\to G_1\times G_2$ is continuous, you only
need to show that $\phi_1:(G_1\times G_2)
\times(G_1\times G_2)\to G_1$ and $\phi_2:(G_1\times G_2)
\times(G_1\times G_2)\to G_2$ are continuous where the $\phi_j$ are
the first and second components of $\mu$.
(It's a general fact in topology that the continuous maps
$Y$ to $X_1\times X_2$ are the $F=(f_1,f_2)$ where the $f_j:Y\to X_j$
are continuous.)

It's easy to see $\phi_j$ are continuous. Indeed $\phi_j$
is the composite of the projection to $G_j\times G_j$ with the
multiplication $\mu_j$.

Comment: I should point out that this argument works for group objects in any category with finite products.

Comment: What about infinite products of topological groups?

Comment: @WilliamElliot : have a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15199).